# Is it possible to restart Netbean's Tomcat bundled version?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I'm writing a shell script in order to clean & build (with `Maven`) and automatically deploy the resulting war into `Tomcat's` webapps folder.
The only problem is I can't find `Tomcat's` binaries folder, thus I'm not able to restart it.

Question is: Is it possible to manually restart `Tomcat` without having to do it via `IDE`? Where are `Tomcat's` binaries?

Answer (score 0):

To find out the path, open the services view with "Window|Services". Choose the tomcat and open the properties/reconfigure via the context menu. The path is configured there.

Comment: I already checked that out, unfortunately the only scripts available are those under /usr/local/apache-tomcat-version/, which is not the directory in which the war archives are deployed, instead, they are deployed under /home/user/.netbeans/version/apache-tomcat-version/webapps, but there aren't scripts there.

Comment: Install a separate tomcat (which contains these scripts) and then configure it as application server at Windows|Services